# UIPanGestureRecognizer: Why there is no StateEnded every time

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm using a UIPanGestureRecognizer to detect and compute the move of the finger. My problem is that something the following sequences of events is triggered:

StateBegan
StateChanged
StateChanged
StateChanged
StateEnded

But sometimes only this sequence for the same user interaction

StateChanged
StateChanged
StateChanged

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panHandler:)];
panRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
panRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[panRecognizer setDelaysTouchesBegan:NO];
[panRecognizer setDelaysTouchesEnded:NO];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
}

-(void)panHandler:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
   //gesture hanlding here
   if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
      // Do smth here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it can be cancelled.
From the documentation :

```
Possible ----> Began ----> [Changed] ----> Cancelled
Possible ----> Began ----> [Changed] ----> Ended
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: Yeah but even I don't get the Cancelled state ... neither the Began state

Comment: Strange. You should have those, here is the documentation :

 A panning gesture is continuous. It begins (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) when the minimum number of fingers allowed (minimumNumberOfTouches) has moved enough to be considered a pan. It changes (UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) when a finger moves while at least the minimum number of fingers are pressed down. It ends (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) when all fingers are lifted.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the case. The StateChanged are fired correctly but not the StateBegan and StateEnded

Comment: Your code is not open source ? have you tried to create a new project from scratch, and see if it's working or not ?

Comment: My code has not more than what I posted. I'll try to create a new project from scratch but I'm pretty sure the behavior will be the same. Maybe there is a reset or smth to be performed after the StateEnded ..